# How to set an int to arduino from c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, arduino

I'm working in a project to control a fan depending on the temperature using arduino and C#, the catch here is that I need an option for the user to provide input temperature in which the fan will turn on.
I am using C# and an arduino uno for this and i have manage to show the temperature value in the C# interface but when i try to send the int, the value doesnt reach the arduino.

I have been investigating and have seen that turning the int into bytes will fix the problem but I don't understand how this works and how to put this in the code.

### Here is my C# Code for that specific button:

Here is supposed to grab the value from the textbox and convert it to bytes.

```
private void cmdSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(SP.IsOpen)
            {
                int temp = Int32.Parse(txttemp.Text);
                byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(temp);
                SP.Write(b,0,4);
            }
        }
```

### And here is my arduino code:

Here the variable T is supposed to be the one to receive the value from C# and change the Max temp in which the fan will turn on.

```
float temperatura = 0; //variable for the temperature
int fan = 8; //pin of the fan
int T;

void setup(){

 Serial.begin (9600); //inicia comunicacion serial

 pinMode(fan,OUTPUT);//configuracion del pin 8
}

void loop(){
//Calcula la temperatura usando como referencia 5v
temperatura = (5.0 * analogRead(0)*100.0)/1023.0;
Serial.println (temperatura); //writes temperature in the serial
delay (500);

//esto enciende y apaga el ventlador
if (temperatura < T){//change the number to the range you desire
  digitalWrite(fan, LOW);

}else
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way, which ensures you also a great and stable performance, is the usage of the [CmdMessenger](https://github.com/thijse/Arduino-Libraries/tree/master/CmdMessenger) library for the Arduino / C# communication. You can integrate and modify the library and the [examples](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/CmdMessenger) very simple. There is also an example of an integer plot. I hope this helps you.

Comment: thank you for the answer, sadly i dont know much of arduino to implement that library and also dont have much time to study it, this is for a school project.
Anyway i found and "easy" answer to my problem and i finish the code.